# Why does iOS think that I'm connecting my 3.5mm to Lightning adapter for the first time?

Tags: ios, audio, lightning

As of iOS 14.2, when connecting a Lightning adapter to an iOS device for the first time (the 3.5mm to Lightning cable being a good example of this), a dialog appears asking the user to choose whether this device is connecting a pair of headphones; if this option is chosen, iOS will then log volume output levels, saving these to the Health app and displaying notifications if they exceed the recommended levels. Whilst this feature is working as expected, I've noticed that despite using the same 3.5mm to Lightning adapter, when connecting this to the Lightning port iOS will sometimes display this dialog again - almost as if it thinks that this adapter is being used for the first time. Is there any way to stop this dialog from appearing?